# Flask - How to send a value to JavaScript function during Python script to update Progress Bar?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I have as an example, two scripts:

- `home.html`
- `views.py`

`views.py` has a function in it with various tasks e.g.:

```
def home()
    list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    total1 = 0
    for x in list1:
        total1 += x

    list2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
    total2 = 0
    for x in list2:
        total2 += x

return render_template("home.html")
```

`home.html` has a JavaScript function in it which updates a html/css progressbar depending on what the variable `'value'` is:

```
<script>
    function updateProgressBar(progressBar, value) {
        value = Math.round(value);
        progressBar.querySelector(".progress__fill").style.width = `${value}%`;
        progressBar.querySelector(".progress__text").textContent = `${value}%`;
    }
</script>
```

The python function can vary in completion time. As a way of updating the user of the progress, after every task (i.e. `total1` complete, `total2` complete) is done in `home()`, I want to send a value to the JavaScript function so it can update the progress bar on `home.html` e.g. if there were 5 tasks in `home()`, it might send the value 20 after task 1, then 40 after task 2 etc.

I am new to 'web development' so struggling to do this and would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to send the data from flask:

```py
# ...
return render_template("home.html", **{
    'total1': total1,
    'total2': total2
})
```

Then add two hidden elements in the html you need to use the variables:

```html
<p id="total1" style="display:none;">{{ total1 }}</p>
<p id="total2" style="display:none;">{{ total2 }}</p>
```

Then use JavaScript to load in those element's data:

```js
const total1 = document.getElementById('total1');
const total2 = document.getElementById('total2');
// ...
```

Then you are free to use total1 and total2 in your JavaScript file.

**A better solution** would be if the JavaScript file you have would make an AJAX request towards your flask server, where the server could have a separate function to handle the request and send the data.

Comment: Thank you Martin for your quick response. I will certainly look at AJAX requesting. Regarding your solution, and before I implement. Would the 'total1', 'total2' variables not be sent until they were all complete (rather than after after every task) if it is being returned in the render_template?

Comment: This version only sends the 'totals' when they are calculated, with using AJAX you can do it differently, here is a nice article about it: https://towardsdatascience.com/using-python-flask-and-ajax-to-pass-information-between-the-client-and-server-90670c64d688